# GeoPandas gaps after dissolve

Tags: python, geopandas, dissolve, gap, tolerance

I have a GeoDataFrame and I use `dissolve` to remove polygon boundaries.

```py
forests_dis = forests.dissolve(by='Forest').explode()
```

But there are gaps in the output (black lines).
[image: lines in the dissolve shapefile]

If I zoom a lot, then I see a very small gap... It is just a few cm but I need to find a way and remove them.

[image]

Is there a way to use tolerance and remove these gaps?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the coordinate system of data is projected (EPSG: 3857) and its unit is meter. So try `buffer` tool with small positive and negative value, respectively

```
forests.dissolve(by='Forest').explode().buffer(0.05).buffer(-0.05) # 0.05: 5 cm
```